# Markdown for C#/WPF Project (MarkdownSharp)

Tags: c#, wpf, markdown

i did some finding and found theres a project [markdown sharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) which is used by stack overflow?

> Open source C# implementation of
>   Markdown processor, as featured on
>   Stack Overflow.

so anyway, i downloaded it. but how do i use it? if possible any code samples or tutorials? theres none to get me started in that google code site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ah. i found the answer.

```
Markdown markdown = new Markdown();
markdown.Transform(txtEditor.Text);
```

docs: Markdown.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Transforms the provided Markdown-formatted text to HTML;  
/// see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown
/// </summary>
...
public string Transform(string text) { ... }
```

i found out abt this reading the inline docs. in php, web call it phpDoc but in C# i wonder whats it called.

Comment: They’re usually called XML comments or XML documentation.