# How can I let a user insert formatted text, images, and attachments into an MVC Edit field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to MVC and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction here.  I have basic CRUD functionality down but would like to allow users to format their text, insert images within the body of a field, and add attachments within the body of the field.  Where is a good place to start for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to make a simple textarea that can save your text in your database then after that you can change that textarea and use some plug-ins like **ckeditor** (references: http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor, http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), you may also like to use **nicEdit** which I'm also using right now (http://nicedit.com/), or you may want to use **WYSIWYM Markdown Editor[wmd]** (https://github.com/derobins/wmd, http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) like this one on stack overflow.. And another one **Rich Text Editor [RTE]** (demo is here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm, main site is here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the markdown editor for formatting the text and inserting images, below are some useful links

[An ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper Extension Method for Markdown using MarkdownSharp](http://blog.dantup.com/2011/03/an-asp-net-mvc-htmlhelper-extension-method-for-markdown-using-markdownsharp)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/can-i-use-stack-overflows-reengineered-wmd-editor

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592423/1679410

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/html/